# Arabic letter have different shapes when search in php mysql all result do not appear

Tags: php, mysql

i have problem in search
arabic letter have different shapes for one letter like

```
أ  إ  ا
ي ى
ه ة
```

all these letters have different unicode
i want to union search when enter letter like (ا)the query must get all word contain
all other shape of `(ا) (أ-إ-ا)`

i make input field with id search

```
$search = $_POST['search'];
$stmt = $con->prepare("select * from `newdrs` 
INNER JOIN `district` ON newdrs.prosec=district.DistCode
INNER JOIN `case_kind` ON newdrs.case_kind=case_kind.id
where accused_names like'%$search%' ");
$stmt->execute();
$employee_details = $stmt->fetchAll(PDO::FETCH_ASSOC);
```

i want to search with one letter shapes and get all other shame

```
أحمد
احمد
إحمد
```

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/279170/utf-8-all-the-way-through

Answer (score 0):

**Disclaimer**: I have no knowledge of Arabic and this answer borrows heavily from [this article](https://a-essam.medium.com/arabic-case-insensitive-in-database-systems-how-to-solve-alef-with-and-without-hamza-problem-c54ee6d40bed) by Ahmed Essam.

---

You have two options - normalisation or custom collation.

#### Normalisation

You could add a column to store a normalised form of the `accused_names` column and use triggers to populate/update the normalised column:

```sql
CREATE TABLE newdrs (
    id INT AUTO_INCREMENT PRIMARY KEY,
    accused_names VARCHAR(255),
    accused_names_normalized VARCHAR(255)
);

DELIMITER $$
CREATE FUNCTION `normalize_name`(s VARCHAR(255)) RETURNS varchar(255)
    DETERMINISTIC
BEGIN
    SET s = REGEXP_REPLACE(s, 'ة', 'ه');
    SET s = REGEXP_REPLACE(s, 'ي', 'ى');
    SET s = REGEXP_REPLACE(s, 'إ|أ|آ', 'ا');
    RETURN REGEXP_REPLACE(s, '|ً|ُ|ِ|ٍ|ٌ|ّ', '');
END$$
DELIMITER ;

CREATE TRIGGER newdrs_before_insert BEFORE INSERT ON newdrs
    FOR EACH ROW SET NEW.accused_names_normalized = normalize_name(NEW.accused_names);

CREATE TRIGGER newdrs_before_update BEFORE UPDATE ON newdrs
    FOR EACH ROW SET NEW.accused_names_normalized = normalize_name(NEW.accused_names);

INSERT INTO newdrs (accused_names) VALUES ('أحمد'), ('احمد'), ('إحمد');
```

**Note**: the pattern and replacement are showing in reverse in the UDF above due to the rtl text. I couldn't figure out how to stop this happening on SO. The same happens on [db<>fiddle](https://dbfiddle.uk/bfQJZB2q).

```sql
SELECT * FROM newdrs WHERE accused_names = 'أحمد';
```

Outputs:

| id | accused_names | accused_names_normalized |
| --- | --- | --- |
| 1 | أحمد | احمد |

```sql
SELECT * FROM newdrs WHERE accused_names_normalized = normalize_name('أحمد');
```

Outputs:

| id | accused_names | accused_names_normalized |
| --- | --- | --- |
| 1 | أحمد | احمد |
| 2 | احمد | احمد |
| 3 | إحمد | احمد |

Here's a [db<>fiddle](https://dbfiddle.uk/bfQJZB2q).

#### Custom collation

([deprecated as of MySQL 8.0.33](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/8.0/en/adding-collation.html#:%7E:text=User%2Ddefined%20collations%20are%20deprecated))

MySQL docs:

- [Adding a UCA Collation to a Unicode Character Set](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/8.0/en/adding-collation-unicode-uca.html)
- [Defining a UCA Collation Using LDML Syntax](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/8.0/en/ldml-collation-example.html)
- [Choosing a Collation ID](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/8.0/en/adding-collation-choosing-id.html)

Execute the following query to locate the charsets in your installation:

```
SHOW VARIABLES LIKE 'character_sets_dir';
```

Output for my local Win instance:

| Variable_name | Value |
| --- | --- |
| character_sets_dir | C:\Program Files\MySQL\MySQL Server 8.0\share\charsets\ |

Add the below collation (or whole charset, depending on whether it already exists) to your `Index.xml` file and then restart MySQL. It is important to take a backup of this file before you start tweaking it.

```xml
<charset name="utf8mb4">
  <family>Unicode</family>
  <description>UTF-8 Unicode</description>
  <collation name="utf8mb4_arabic_ci" id="1030">
    <rules>
      <reset>\u0627</reset>   <!-- Alef 'ا' -->
      <i>\u0623</i>           <!-- Alef With Hamza Above 'أ' -->
      <i>\u0625</i>           <!-- Alef With Hamza Below 'إ' -->
      <i>\u0622</i>           <!-- Alef With Madda Above 'آ' -->
    </rules>
    <rules>
      <reset>\u0649</reset>   <!-- Alef Maksura 'ى' -->
      <i>\u064A</i>           <!-- Yeh 'ي' -->
    </rules>
    <rules>
      <reset>\u0629</reset>   <!-- Teh Marbuta 'ة' -->
      <i>\u0647</i>           <!-- Heh 'ه' -->
    </rules>
    <rules>
      <reset>\u0000</reset>   <!-- Unicode value of NULL  -->
      <i>\u064E</i>           <!-- Fatha 'َ' -->
      <i>\u064F</i>           <!-- Damma 'ُ' -->
      <i>\u0650</i>           <!-- Kasra 'ِ' -->
      <i>\u0651</i>           <!-- Shadda 'ّ' -->
      <i>\u064F</i>           <!-- Sukun 'ْ' -->
      <i>\u064B</i>           <!-- Fathatan 'ً' -->
      <i>\u064C</i>           <!-- Dammatan 'ٌ' -->
      <i>\u064D</i>           <!-- Kasratan 'ٍ' -->
    </rules>
  </collation>
</charset>
```

After restarting MySQL, run the following query to check that your new collation has been added:

```sql
SHOW COLLATION LIKE 'utf8mb4_arabic_ci';
```

I created the following test table:

```sql
CREATE TABLE newdrs2 (
    id INT AUTO_INCREMENT PRIMARY KEY,
    accused_names VARCHAR(255) COLLATE utf8mb4_arabic_ci
);
INSERT INTO newdrs2 (accused_names) VALUES ('أحمد'), ('احمد'), ('إحمد');
```

And the following query:

```sql
SELECT * FROM newdrs2 WHERE accused_names = 'أحمد';
```

Outputs:

| id | accused_names |
| --- | --- |
| 1 | أحمد |
| 2 | احمد |
| 3 | إحمد |

**Reference**: this is heavily based on [this article](https://a-essam.medium.com/arabic-case-insensitive-in-database-systems-how-to-solve-alef-with-and-without-hamza-problem-c54ee6d40bed) by Ahmed Essam.